# AWS EMR dependencies

Tags: scala, amazon-emr

I am trying to translate the Java code in ["End-to-End Amazon EMR Java Source Code Sample"](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-common-programming-sample.html) to Scala.  I am using SBT for dependency management.  Here are my current relevant dependencies in `build.sbt`:

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk
libraryDependencies += "com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk" % "1.2.1"
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.jackson/jackson-core-asl
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-core
libraryDependencies += "com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk-core" % "1.9.17"
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-emr
libraryDependencies += "com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk-emr" % "1.9.0"
```

The first import that does not compile is:

```
import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSStaticCredentialsProvider
```

What SBT dependency am I missing for this import?

Here are the errors from `sbt compile`.

```
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /Users/paulreiners/dev/tv-datascience-aws/target/scala-2.11/classes ...
[error] /Users/paulreiners/dev/tv-datascience-aws/src/main/scala/Main.scala:3:8: object AWSStaticCredentialsProvider is not a member of package com.amazonaws.auth
[error] import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSStaticCredentialsProvider
[error]        ^
[error] /Users/paulreiners/dev/tv-datascience-aws/src/main/scala/Main.scala:6:8: object AmazonElasticMapReduceClientBuilder is not a member of package com.amazonaws.services.elasticmapreduce
[error] import com.amazonaws.services.elasticmapreduce.AmazonElasticMapReduceClientBuilder
[error]        ^
[error] /Users/paulreiners/dev/tv-datascience-aws/src/main/scala/Main.scala:18:15: not found: value AmazonElasticMapReduceClientBuilder
[error]     val emr = AmazonElasticMapReduceClientBuilder.defaultClient()
[error]               ^
[error] three errors found
[error] (Compile / compileIncremental) Compilation failed
```

Comment: How do you compile it? Did you try `sbt compile` from console?

Answer (score 1):

You need a newer version of `aws-java-sdk`:

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk
libraryDependencies += "com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk" % "1.11.531"
```